# Fixing tear in vinyl floor

Tags: vinyl-flooring

[image]

My dog locked herself in the bathroom while I was gone & tore up a gap in the vinyl on the floor. This is a rental so I want to repair it if possible. Any tips? I have the ripped pieces in tact.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to fix that.  Just replace the bathroom flooring.  A small area won't be expensive if you DIY.

Maybe wait until you are ready to move if the dog could repeat this.  It wouldn't hurt to talk to the landlord.  If the flooring needs to be replaced, they might prefer something different, in which case they might agree to just taking an amount you would have spent on the repair (without you having to be responsible for the work).

Answer (score 0):

That is terrible flooring. I would replace it with LVP, rated for bathrooms. Do not buy lvp less than 6 mm thick, seriously, every time I went even to 5 mm, something went wrong, it's too brittle or something. That tear isn't repairable and, the landlord would do well to put better stuff in there. Maybe work out a deal with him. The LVP is really easy to install.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/175188)